# Partial sort of multipling vector by matrix

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have this code, which is doing following: multiply numpy vector by matrix and take topN elements in this row.

```
import bottleneck as bn
import numpy as np

res_row = np.array(np.dot(row, q_matrix))
topn_elements = bn.argpartition(-1 * res_row, top_n)[0][:N]  # -1 to get N largest values
```

What I don't want to do: I don't want to store array between multipling and partial sort, in my case it is `res_row`. Maybe, there is some way to make heap and add each resulting element of multipling?

Comment: If you're worried about storing, then calling `np.array` is the last think you want there - not only have you stored it once, but then `np.array` makes another copy!

Comment: Is there something special/peculiar/interesting about `row, q_matrix` that we can exploit?

Comment: @Cleb, deleted `recrow`.

@Divakar, about `row, q_matrix` - row size is about 250, matrix - 250 * 5 million. And I need only top100 elements.

Comment: @Eric but as I understand, `bn.argpartition` needs array, and `np.dot` generates matrix. Anyway, after `res_row = np.array(np.dot(row, q_matrix))` only one copy will be left. Am I right?

Comment: @AlexLoo: `np.dot` generates whatever you pass to it. If `q_matrix` and `row` are both `np.array`s (which I would really recommend you make them). `np.asarray()` is a better option if you do have a matrix, because that doesn't make a copy if it can avoid it. Yes, only one copy will be left - but if you're happy to have two temporary copies, why are you worried about storing one?

Comment: Why not just use `np.partition` here?

Comment: @Eric now I see now, that I made a mistake about storing two copies. But still I would like not to store even one full result array.

Comment: @Eric about `np.partition`: don't really see difference with my decision: in one case I get first topN sorted, in another not sorted. It doesn't really matter, sorting first N elements won't take much time

Comment: @AlexLoo: Sorry, I meant `np.argpartition`. My point was that `bottleneck` is not needed, because those functions are built into numpy now.

Comment: Can you  explain why you do not want to store the result? Are you willing to partition in place?

Comment: @Eric i am using this code on pyspark. I broadcast (share) `q_matrix` and execute this code in parallel, so when after multiply but before argpartition I have millions of `res_row`s. It takes lot's of memory to store this data.
Of course, I can convert all `double` to `float16` and won't have any troubles with memory, but want to know, if there is another way.